# How To Terminate Any Running Task Of Application When Logout

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm creating a react-native mobile app to support playing videos. And I am facing to a problem that after users logout, they still can hear video sound in the login screen.

Here are steps:

- Login app.
- See a list of video thumbnail and just press on one to chose to play.
- The app will navigate to another view, I call it VideoView.
- While it is still loading video, go back.
- Logout. Session killed of course.
- There in the login screen, users will hear the voice of the video playing (it just finished loading and get play)

I searched through out but people just discus about how to kill process when exit app.

I also think of the way that after logout, I should call restart app. But for me seem not correct.

Here is how I go back:

```
_goBack() {
return () => {
  this.props.navigation.goBack();
};
}
```

Here is how I logout:

```
_logOut = () => {
session.clear();

const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Auth' }),
  ],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
}
```

Any help would be welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: can you add code that starts video or sound?

Comment: I put the video link into the player and let it handles.
The problem seems that the view of the player not get killed when I get out of it.

Comment: It was all my mistake. The video player did not handle for what should happen when detaching from window. Case closed.